# Spring MVC and Hibernate: NoClassDefFoundError for Controller class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making a small flashcard program to help learn Spring MVC and Hibernate. I made the following program with only JDBC and it worked, but when I edited it to include Hibernate, it broke with the following error when I attempt to run the program:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\FlashCard\WEB-INF\classes\com\moisen\controller\HomeController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.moisen.controller.HomeController
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.moisen.controller.HomeController
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is my HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    private static final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    private static final JdbcDao dao = context.getBean("jdbcDao", JdbcDao.class);


    private List<Category> categories;
    private Category currentCategory;
    private List<Track> tracks;
    private Track currentTrack;
    private List<FlashCard> flashCards;
    private FlashCard currentFlashCard;
    private Map<Integer, FlashCard> flashCardMap;
    private Map<Integer, Category> categoryMap;
    private Map<Integer, Track> trackMap;
    private int flashCardIndex;

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        //ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        //JdbcDao dao = context.getBean("jdbcDao", JdbcDao.class);
        HibernateDao dao = context.getBean("hibernateDao", HibernateDao.class);


        setCategories(dao.getCategories());
        setCategoryMap(new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Category>());
        for (Category category : getCategories()) {
            getCategoryMap().put(category.getId(), category);
        }
        model.addAttribute("categories", getCategories() );

        return "home";
    }
    ...
```

spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.moisen." />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flashcard" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcDao" class="com.moisen.dao.JdbcDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateDao" class="com.moisen.dao.HibernateDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" ref="org.moisen.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

My HibernateDao:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateDao implements DaoType{
    //private Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    //private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; // = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    private Session session;

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        setSession(getSessionFactory().openSession());
        Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("Category.all");
        return (List<Category>) query.list();
        //return (List<Category>) getSession().createQuery("from Category order by name").list();
    }
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your spring config. your component-scan mentions 2 packages, but not the package where the controller is supposed to be. Check that you have specified the correct packages in the spring configuration files.

Comment: Check package name on top of controller class. you specified in component scan com.moisen.model but in the log its look for com.moisen.controller...or change coponent scan to com.moisen.controller or only com.moisen.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Stack Trace posted, sorry.

Comment: @Augusto I had that originally, but it didn't work so I took it out to see if it would work. I put back in "com.moisen." and get the same error.

Comment: @jdev I did com.moisen. and got the same error. Originally I had com.moisen.controller but I took it out because of this error.

Comment: Ok, there's much more at work here. Please post your web.xml as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok I posted it as the last entry. Thanks.

Comment: which spring conf file is this? is it `servlet-context.xml` or `root-context.xml`?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen : Do you see an ExceptionInInitializerError somewhere down in the stacktrace. If yes, check this out http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the following component scanning for a base package. In the spring configuration, you have defined it as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.moisen." />
```

However, you do not need the `.` at the end of the package name. I would change the above line to the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.moisen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you kept context:component-scan tag inside spring.xml instead of root-context.xml file which is loaded on start-up as per web.xml configuration, I am not sure why you need to instantiate another application context `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")` in HomeController?

Add all your spring config files in web.xml, and auto-wire beans like hibernateDao in home controller.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:root-context.xml
        classpath:spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```